# Translate StructureMap component registration to Autofac version

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, autofac, structuremap

I'm new to Autofac and have the following StructureMap component registrations that I would like to translate, but am concerned that my implementation may not be done the recommended way. Autofac puts great emphasis on the fact that you should not be resolving outside of a lifetime scope (i.e. container.Resolve), but of course, `container.BeginLifetimeScope()` isn't available until the `ContainerBuilder` is built.

```
 For<ISessionSource>().Singleton().Use<NHibernateSessionSource>();

 For<ISession>().Use(ctx => {
    var unitOfWork = (INHibernateUnitOfWork)ctx.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
    return unitOfWork.Session;
 });             

 For<IUnitOfWork>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use<NHibernateUnitOfWork>();
```

Autofac:

```
 builder.RegisterType<NHibernateSessionSource>().As<ISessionSource>().SingleInstance();

 // Is the following recommended? Define that whenever request an `ISession` it should return the `Session` property of the concrete implementation of `INHibernateUnitOfWork`:
 builder.Register(ctx =>
 {
     var unitOfWork = (INHibernateUnitOfWork)ctx.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>();
     return unitOfWork.Session;
 }).As<ISession>().InstancePerRequest(); 

 builder.RegisterType<NHibernateUnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get your concerns. The implementation looks fine to me, and **very** close to the StructureMap one. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Yes, it's very close to the StructureMap one (albeit I improved it from my first initial implementation as I wrote the question, as often happens ;-). My concern is that Autofac goes out of its way to recommend not resolving services directly from root container, but rather from nested LifetimeScopes. However, you cannot do so prior to building the container. I'm quite sure this is the correct implementation, but am completely new to Autofac, so wanting to ensure not missing anything (e.g. a way to do something like container.BeginLifetimeScope prior to building the container).

Comment: "While it is possible to resolve components right from the root container, doing this through your application in some cases may result in a memory leak. It is recommended you always resolve components from a lifetime scope where possible to make sure service instances are properly disposed and garbage collected."

Comment: IUnitOfWork implements IDisposable, so we're good on that front as the concrete implementations of ISession and IUnitOfWork both have InstancePerRequest lifetimes, while only the singleton implementation of ISessionSource is SingleInstance lifetime.

Comment: I think all containers recommend not to resolve services from the root container but rather from nested scopes - or nested containers as StructureMap calls them. I don't see where you resolve services from the root container in your case. You do take advantage of lambda-based registrations, but the `ctx` variable in your Autofac example doesn't represent the root container, but rather the current context when the lambda will be executed. By looking at your registrations, I'm fairly confident to say that the current context will be an HTTP request scoped context.

Comment: Many thanks for the confirmation! And also for pointing out that ctx is not actually root, but the current context (obvious in retrospect).

Comment: glad I could help. I summarised that in an answer for future reference.

Comment: Thanks. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what we got out from the comments.

The OP was worried that `ctx` in the lambda represented the root container, and as a result thought that these registrations didn't stick to best practices since Autofac - like any other IoC container - advises against resolving services from the root container.

It turns out that, in fact, `ctx` represents the current resolution context at the time of the lambda execution.

The use of `InstancePerRequest` in the registrations points towards the fact `ctx` will, in this case, be the HTTP request lifetime scope context.

All in all, the current Autofac registrations look good and similar to the StructureMap ones.